# Classify a variable depending on the number of NAs in R

Tags: r, count, tidyverse, na, missing-data

I have 2 scenarios:

- One where I would like to define a new variable (called `df$x1`) depending on whether there are 16 NAs in 16 other different columns. My proposed code would be:

  `cols <- 1:16`

  `df %>% mutate(x1=ifelse(rowSums(df[cols] ==NA, na.rm = TRUE) ==16) ,'Yes', 'No')))`
- On the second scenario, I would like to check whether there is at least 1 NA in a list of 12 variables

How would you do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing with your 1st approach except `NA`'s are checked with `is.na` -

```
cols <- 1:12

df$x1 <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) > 0, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! - is there any reason why you put 1:12 rather than 1:16? (just checking)  and also, for the second scenario, would it be the same but for example 
cols2<-1:12 df$Second_Scenario<- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df[cols2]))> 1, 'Yes', 'No')

Comment: Ohh..I thought you already have an answer for first scenario. I was answering for the second one. You can make this work for the 1st one as - `df$x1 <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) == 16 , 'Yes', 'No')`

Comment: Fab! million thanks once again! (you always answer my questions!)

Answer (score 1):

1s't Scenario: `df$x1 <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df[,cols])) == 16, "Yes", "No")`